# Implementing a simplified C++ vector class copy - won't compile

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Chapter 11 of Accelerated C++ covers implementing template classes, using a simplified version of the STL's vector class as an example. Exercise 11-6 wants us to add the `.erase()` and `.clear()` methods to the class, so first I copied the final code directly from the book and tried to compile, but it failed. I then moved all the function definitions into the .h file (removing the `Vec<T>::` etc. stuff as necessary) and compiled just my main.cpp, which worked.

Here's all of my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vec.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    Vec<int> v;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);

    for(Vec<int>::const_iterator iter = v.begin();
        iter != v.end(); ++iter)
        cout << *iter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Vec.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_Vec_h
#define GUARD_Vec_h

#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

template <class T> class Vec {
public:
    // member variables
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

    // constructors + destructors
    Vec() { create(); }
    explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& t = T()) { create(n, t); }
    Vec(const Vec& v) { create(v.begin(), v.end()); }
    ~Vec() { uncreate(); }

    // methods
    T& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }

    void push_back(const T& t) {
        if (avail == limit)
            grow();
        unchecked_append(t);
    }

    size_type size() const { return avail - data; }

    iterator begin() { return data; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return data; }

    iterator end() { return avail; }
    const_iterator end() const { return avail; }

private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;

    std::allocator<T> alloc;

    void create();
    void create(size_type, const T&);
    void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

    void uncreate();

    void grow();
    void unchecked_append(const T&);
};

#endif GUARD_Vec_h
```

Vec.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include "Vec.h"

using std::allocator;
using std::max;
using std::uninitialized_copy;
using std::uninitialized_fill;
using std::ptrdiff_t;

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create()
{
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(n);
    limit = avail = data + n;
    uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(j - i);
    limit = avail = uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::uncreate()
{
    if (data) {
        iterator it = avail;
        while (it != data)
            alloc.destroy(--it);

        alloc.deallocate(data, limit - data);
    }

    data = limit = avail = 0;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::grow()
{
    size_type new_size = max(2 * (limit - data), ptrdiff_t(1));

    iterator new_data = alloc.allocate(new_size);
    iterator new_avail = uninitialized_copy(data, avail, new_data);

    uncreate();

    data = new_data;
    avail = new_avail;
    limit = data + new_size;
}

template <class T> void Vec<T>::unchecked_append(const T& val)
{
    alloc.construct(avail++, val);
}
```

Why doesn't this compile?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that the book didn't explain why template definitions must go in header files... In any case, read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.15).

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.12

Comment: It sounds like the author put split `Vec` into .h and .cpp files. If that's the case, he must have a pretty fancy compiler!

Comment: Hm, maybe I misread/misremember, but I don't recall the book mentioning that, though I suspect it's in there (Accelerated C++ seems to be an overall really good book)... thanks for the help guys!          *EDIT* On second thought.. the book did mention this a few chapters back when templates were first introduced.. my fault for forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with any and all of the template functions.  When you write a Template function, the compiler *instantiates* the template--that is, it creates a specific version of the function with the types you need to run the code.  So when you call

```
Vec<int> v;
```

The compiler makes code for a Vec and any function of that type you call.  The compiler needs to have access to the templated function definitions while making the code for the main file, because it has to know what kind of code to make for the object file before it goes to link the other files.